# Disable deletes via CLI using IAM permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I'd like to prevent deletions via remote tools (like Terraform or the CLI) for an account for resources like RDS. I have included my existing Terraform configuration. Sadly this prevents all AWS console access, and I suspect that I am misusing the `aws:ViaAWSService` check.

In short: I'd like to prevent CLI/remote deletes but allow AWS Console deletes.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "delete_prevention" {
  statement {
    sid = "PreventDelete"
    effect = "Deny"

    actions = [
      "rds:Delete*",
      "ec2:Delete*",
      "ec2:TerminateInstances",
      "ec2:Disassociate*",
      "elasticache:Delete*",
      "s3:Delete*",
      "dynamodb:DeleteTable",
      "route53:Delete*",
      "lambda:Delete*",
      "lambda:RemovePermission",
      "sns:Delete*",
      "secretsmanager:Delete*",
      "ssm:Delete*",
      "ecr:Delete*",
      "acm:Delete*",
      "ses:Delete*"
    ]

    resources = ["*"]

    condition {
      test     = "BoolIfExists"
      values   = ["false"]
      variable = "aws:ViaAWSService"
    }

    dynamic "condition" {
      for_each = local.fuzzy_delete_protect
      content {
        test     = "StringLikeIfExists"
        values   = condition.value
        variable = "aws:RequestTag/${condition.key}"
      }
    }

    dynamic "condition" {
      for_each = local.exact_delete_protect
      content {
        test     = "StringEqualsIfExists"
        values   = condition.value
        variable = "aws:RequestTag/${condition.key}"
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "delete_prevention" {
  count = length(var.delete_protect_tags) > 0 ? 1 : 0
  name = "prevent-tool-delete"
  description = "Prevents deletion of Terraform labeled resources from anything but the console."
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.delete_prevention.json
}
```

Comment: Does it actually matter how a resource is deleted (from the AWS console vs. some other client)? Typically you can't gate this activity reliably by client type.

Comment: @jarmod Yes. I want to prevent running an automated tool from a developer's machine and have the tools only run via approved CI/CD. For instance: you can tear down all resources quickly with Terraform and that is dangerous in a production environment. I'd still like to allow them to have full access via the AWS console.

Comment: In that case, your users shouldn't have permissions for that deployed (production?) environment. You can do this through IAM (e.g. conditions on resource ARNs), or IAM permissions with conditional resource tagging, or best of all, different AWS accounts for prod workloads vs. developer workloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can come close to what you want by making your Deny statement only apply [when MFA is not present](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-multifactorauthpresent).  It's still possible to call [`sts:GetSessionToken`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetSessionToken.html) with MFA from other tools (which would return a new token that has MFA) but automation isn't going to have access to MFA unless you have odd automation or your person goes into a bunch of extra effort.